# Building a Case Statement with TIME

Tags: sql, time, sas

This is a sample of my code.

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE SUCCESS_TIME_INTERVALS AS

SELECT

A.*,

CASE 

WHEN A.TIME BETWEEN  9:00:00 AND 11:00:00 THEN '9AM_11AM'

WHEN A.TIME BETWEEN 11:00:00 AND 13:00:00 THEN '11AM_1PM'

ELSE 'OTHER' END AS TIME_INTERVALS

FROM TABLE1 A

;QUIT;
```

I get this error when I run my code

> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !!, *, **,
>   +, -, /, AND, ||.
>
> ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Not sure how to fix this.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you run the SELECT stand-alone?

Comment: Depends on what is in the variable TIME.  If it is a numeric variable with time values (ie it looks right when displayed using `TIME.` format) then make sure to use time literals in your query.  `'9:00:00't`

Answer (score 4):

You need single quotes for the time constants:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE SUCCESS_TIME_INTERVALS AS
    SELECT A.*,
           (CASE WHEN A.TIME BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '11:00:00' THEN '9AM_11AM'
                 WHEN A.TIME BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '13:00:00' THEN '11AM_1PM'
                 ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS TIME_INTERVALS
    FROM TABLE1 A;
QUIT;
```

Obviously, if `time` is not a string, then you need to express the constant appropriately:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE SUCCESS_TIME_INTERVALS AS
    SELECT A.*,
           (CASE WHEN A.TIME BETWEEN '09:00:00't AND '11:00:00't THEN '9AM_11AM'
                 WHEN A.TIME BETWEEN '11:00:00't AND '13:00:00't THEN '11AM_1PM'
                 ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS TIME_INTERVALS
    FROM TABLE1 A;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Time constants != strings.  Single/double doesn't matter quote wise, but they should be actual time constants and not strings (assuming it's actually a time field and not a string; and assuming it is a SAS dataset and not a SQL server table.)

Comment: @Joe . . . I have no reason to think that a column called `time` is *not` a string.  It might be a string; I don't think the question is clear on that point.

Comment: Well, then perhaps ask for clarification in the comments first?  Anyhow, thanks for the update.  I would perhaps remove the word "single" still, as in SAS single or double quotes are equally valid in both of these cases, but that's nitpicking.